# ".dist-info directory not found" with pipenv install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, pipenv, snapcraft

I'm trying to install snapcraft's requirements using:

```
pipenv install -r snapcraft/requirements.txt
```

and it fails to install those two dependencies:

> https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/python-apt_1.1.0~beta1build1.tar.xz
>   https://launchpad.net/python-distutils-extra/trunk/2.39/+download/python-distutils-extra-2.39.tar.gz

```
Collecting f3a5fdd from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/python-apt_1.1.0~beta1build1.tar.xz#egg=f3a5fdd 
Installing collected packages: f3a5fdd

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/fgervais/core/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/media/fgervais/core/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "/media/fgervais/core/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 49, in     install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "/media/fgervais/core/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 748, in install
    use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
  File "/media/fgervais/core/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 961, in     move_wheel_files
    warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
  File "/media/fgervais/core/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 316, in move_wheel_files
    assert info_dir, "%s .dist-info directory not found" % req
AssertionError: f3a5fdd .dist-info directory not found
```

Any body know where #egg=f3a5fdd is coming from?

I think this is what cause the issue because this works:

```
pipenv shell
pip3 install https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/python-apt_1.1.0~beta1build1.tar.xz
```

but if I add #egg=f3a5fdd it fails with the same error as pipenv.

Comment: This is the official report for this issue: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2611