# pip fails in installing package

Tags: python, pip

does anyone know what could be wrong here? I am trying to install my own python package, but getting:

```
c:\Python\Python36\Scripts>pip install --index-url yyy xxx
Looking in indexes: yyy
Collecting xxx
Installing collected packages: xxx
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py",
 line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py",
 line 366, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", lin
e 49, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py",
line 760, in install
    use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py",
line 382, in move_wheel_files
    warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 326,
in move_wheel_files
    assert info_dir, "%s .dist-info directory not found" % req
AssertionError: xxx .dist-info directory not found
```

What could be wrong with python or pip and why I am getting:
`AssertionError: xxx .dist-info directory not found`?

Comment: I think the same problem happened here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411699/dist-info-directory-not-found-with-pipenv-install-r-requirements-txt
There's a link there to a github thread, you should check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your Pip caches, that's because regardless of whether you use a venv or your system interpreter if you are using Pip as a package manager it always caches parts of the packages in the computer.

To see where the caches are for your OS [PyPi Caching](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#caching).